# Bottom actionbar like in Instagram

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar

How can I make bottom actionbar like in Instagram? When I split actionbar, it's too low and also all items from menu go bottom, but I need one to stay at the main action bar. How could I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the action bar is not the solution because it will split it only if there is not enough room.

In android L and the new support library there is a new component called `Toolbar` which acts just like a normal ViewGroup. You can position it however you like and you can inflate a a normal menu in it. You also would not need to use the split action bar anymore.